# How to run the jar made from 'lein jar' command?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

This is a follow-up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390268/how-to-setup-the-classpath-when-running-the-jar-made-from-lein-uberjar).

After running 'lein jar', I get 'myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar', which doesn't contain the clojure-1.2.0-beta1.jar and clojure-contrib-1.2.0-beta1.jar.

And running 'lein uberjar' gives me two jar files. The first one (that ends with -standalone.jar) is the jar contains everything, and the second one is the same as the jar generated with 'lein jar'.

This is the question of the jar with the second one. There's no problem running with the first jar, as I explained in the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390268/how-to-setup-the-classpath-when-running-the-jar-made-from-lein-uberjar).

When I run

```
java -cp PATH_TO_THE_CLOJURE_AND_CONTRIB.jar:$CLASSPATH -jar myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

, I get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.lang.IFn
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

What might be wrong, I thought I can use the 'myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar the same way with 'myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar' if I point to the jar files using -cp option.

Is there anything more that I had to do?

### ADDED

```
java -cp ALLTHE_JAR_PATH myproject.core
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Leiningen 1.2, you are probably being hit by a bug whereby dependencies would get deleted prior to the creation of an uberjar (obviously defeating the point of uberjar). Please either downgrade to 1.1 and wait for the new release (which should be arriving shortly) or use a checkout of lein's HEAD (as described in the section on hacking Leiningen in lein's README).

Once you do that, you should be able to produce a standalone jar with `lein uberjar` and say `java -jar name-of-your-standalone.jar` to launch your app.

As an alternative, you can create a regular jar with `lein jar` and say something like `java -cp '$PROJECT_ROOT/lib/*:your-app.jar' your-app.main` (where `your-app.main` is your application's main class; also, replace `$PROJECT_ROOT` with the appropriate path and supply a path to `your-app.jar`, of course). The `lib/*` thing will only work on JDK 1.6; with 1.5 you'd have to include every jar separately. **Note that when using `-jar`, `-cp` and `$CLASSPATH` are ignored; only the classpath specified in the jar's manifest (if any) is taken into account.**

Comment: My uberjar works without any problem, I wanted to know why the jar that I get from 'lein jar' doesn't work with 'java -cp $PROJECT_ROOT/lib*' -jar your-app.jar. Did I have to put your-app.jar into the -cp? Then, what's the other command that I have to call?

Comment: If you specify `-jar`, `-cp` is ignored (and so is `$CLASSPATH`). You'll have to use `-cp` and specify the main class by hand (if it's called `your-app.main`, say `java -cp ... your-app.main`, with any arguments to your `main` method (= the Clojure function `-main`) at the end). I should have noticed this reading the question... will edit it into the answer.

Comment: Incidentally, if uberjar creates jars which do not include the contents of `clojure.jar` and `clojure-contrib.jar` for you, then it is not working without problem. Including the dependencies is the whole point of uberjar! (And it makes the use of `java -jar` possible.)

Comment: Another workaround for the 1.2 bug is to include a :main namespace in project.clj; if you're building an uberjar for distribution, you probably want a -main function anyway. Including AOT in the process avoids the jar clearing bug.

Comment: Ah, right. And I guess it's needed for `-jar` anyway. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: uberjar just runs the repl for me. i swear this worked before